# How to combine 2 tablewidgets (1 column for each one) into a listwidget using the model/view

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I wanna concatenate the items of a column in `tablewidget_1` and the items of a column in `tablewidget_2`, and put the result in a `listwidget` or a `listview`. I m using pyqt5. I know how to set a model to a specific column of a table then affect this model to a listview, but I didn't find a way how to concatenate 2 `tablewidgets` into the model.

here is the code for a model for just one tablewidget:

```py
model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
model.setSourceModel(self.tableWidget.model())

listview.setModel(model)
listview.setModelColumn(0)
```

Comment: How would those column items "joined"? Could those items change in their original tables? Is there a specific reason for using QTableWidget instead of a QTableView?

Comment: example;
 tablewidget1:
column0  
      1              
      2         
      3        
tablewidget2:
column0
      4
      5
      6
what i want is to put into the listwidget like this:
listwidget
1
2
3
4
5

i don t want to change the items in their origin (table1 and table2)

Comment: I just found out about [QConcatenateTablesProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qconcatenatetablesproxymodel.html) which seems to do exactly what you're looking for; it's available since Qt 5.13, which was released in June, but I cannot test it as I've an older version of Qt I cannot update.

Answer (score 0):

The first is to convert the table type model to a list type using a custom [`QAbstractProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html), and then concatenate it using [`QConcatenateTablesProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qconcatenatetablesproxymodel.html#addSourceModel)(PyQt5>=5.13):

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Table2ListProxyModel(QtCore.QIdentityProxyModel):
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 0 if self.sourceModel() is None else 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if self.sourceModel() is None:
            return 0
        return self.sourceModel().rowCount() * self.sourceModel().columnCount()

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if row < 0 or column < 0 or self.sourceModel() is None:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        source_parent = self.mapToSource(parent)
        r = row // self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        c = row % self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        sourceIndex = self.sourceModel().index(r, c, source_parent)
        return self.mapFromSource(sourceIndex)

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        if self.sourceModel() is None or not proxyIndex.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        r = proxyIndex.row() // self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        c = proxyIndex.row() % self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        return self.sourceModel().index(r, c)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        if self.sourceModel() is None or not sourceIndex.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        r = sourceIndex.row() * self.sourceModel().columnCount() + sourceIndex.column()
        c = 0
        return self.createIndex(r, c, sourceIndex.internalPointer())


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._table1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(3, 2)
        self._table2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 3)
        self._table3 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 4)
        self._table4 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(6, 5)

        tables = (self._table1, self._table2, self._table3, self._table4)

        for i, table in enumerate(tables):
            for row in range(table.rowCount()):
                for column in range(table.columnCount()):
                    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{}: {}-{}".format(i, row, column))
                    table.setItem(row, column, it)

        concatenate_proxy_model = QtCore.QConcatenateTablesProxyModel(self)
        concatenate_list_view = QtWidgets.QListView()
        concatenate_list_view.setModel(concatenate_proxy_model)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Table to List:"), 1, 0, 1, len(tables))
        grid_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Results:"), 3, 0, 1, len(tables))
        grid_layout.addWidget(concatenate_list_view, 4, 0, 1, len(tables))

        for i, table in enumerate(tables):
            list_view = QtWidgets.QListView()
            proxy = Table2ListProxyModel(self)
            proxy.setSourceModel(table.model())
            list_view.setModel(proxy)
            concatenate_proxy_model.addSourceModel(proxy)

            grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, i)
            grid_layout.addWidget(list_view, 2, i)

        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```